# Is there a way to arrange the alignment of List Items (LI) when using an image as a bullet?

Tags: css, listitem

I have the following CSS

```
.ul{
    list-style-image:url(/images/bullet.png)
}
```

My bullet.png is 20 x 20px however it is displaying the text at the bottom of the image while I need to display my text in the middle of the image. Is there a way to assign margins and paddings that move only the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reset the paddings and margins.

Use `background-image` property and set a padding of the size of the image (and more if you want some space between your bullet and your text)

```
li
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 20px 0 0;
  background-image:url(/images/bullet.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, its works quite nicely and across browsers. Its a pity that the 'list-style-image' tag has to be worked around and is essentially useless in this respect but as long as it looks good across browsers I guess it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. You can try removing the bullets, put padding on the LI and a background-image aligned left and center: `background: url(images/bullet.png) no-repeat left center;`.